# DiagrammeR example leads to 'could not find function "%>>%" ' error

Tags: r, graph

In R 3.2.0 on Windows, running the example code titled

**"An Example with Data from the nycflights13 Package"**

from

https://github.com/rich-iannone/DiagrammeR

leads to

```
Error: could not find function "%>>%"
```

Full, reproducible example:

http://pastebin.com/Czd06Ais

I have tried this with both the CRAN and development versions of `DiagrammeR` and I tried reinstalling `Rgraphviz` but the results did not change.

Comment: I think this operator comes from the [pipeR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pipeR/pipeR.pdf) package

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! Could you please make this into a solution?

Comment: I think @JasonAizkalns already did and then erased for some reason...

Comment: Yes, someone did and as I clicked the checkbox to make it the accepted solution it had been deleted. I suppose he was second guessing himself or saw your comment and didn't want to steal credit from you.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I erased because your comment suffices and didn't want to take credit. I submitted a pull to the `README.md` file on github.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns it Ok, you can post it. I don't think you took any credit from me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @DavidArenburg's comment, the `%>>%` operator is from the [`pipeR`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pipeR/pipeR.pdf) package. Install it with `install.packages("pipeR")` and then `library(pipeR)` and the code should work.

Note that `%>>%` is a pipeline operator. One could also use the single `>` operator, that is `%>%`, from the [`magrittr`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/index.html) package. For an excellent write-up on the differences, see [this link](http://renkun.me/blog/2014/08/08/difference-between-magrittr-and-pipeR.html)